# How to redirect the user to the home page with jQuery after successful login

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to jQuery and I'm using the post method in my **login.js** file to send a request to my **login.php** script and retrieve an error message depending on the nature of the form data that has been inputted.

All my error messages are working and are correctly displayed in the browser. My problem is that when the user enters valid login credentials, I want to redirect them to a home page. Instead, jQuery is taking my result for a successful login and inserting it into login_error div.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

**login.js**:

```
$(document).ready(
function login_error()
{
    $("#login").click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var postData = $('#login_form').serialize();

        $.post('login.php', postData, function(result)
        {   
            if(result != "match"){
                $('#login_error').html(result);
            }else{
                window.location = 'home.php';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**login.php**:

```
<?php 

include "core/init.php";

$username = $password = "";

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(empty($username) || empty($password)){
        echo '<p class="alert-danger">You didn\'t fill in all the fields.</p>';
    }else if(user_exists($username) === false){ 
        echo '<p class="alert-danger">The username you entered doesn\'t match any account in our records. Sign up for an account.</p>';
    }else if(user_verified($username) === false){
        echo "<p class='alert-danger'><strong>".$username."</strong>&nbspis not a verified username. Check your inbox for a verification email.</p>";
    }else if(check_details($username, $password) === false){
        echo '<p class="alert-danger">The login details you entered don\'t match our records.</p>';
    }else{
        log_in($username, $password);
    }

}else{
    echo '<p class="alert-danger">Oops - something broke! We\'re working to fix this, check back soon.</p>';
}

?>
```

My **log_in** function:

```
function log_in($username, $password){

    $db   = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'forum');
    $sql  = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $sql);

    if($stmt){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $username);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_id);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

        if(!empty($user_id)){
            $_SESSION['id']   = $user_id;
            $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
            echo 'match';
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it echoing 'match' as the error or something else?

Comment: Yes, it's echoing 'match'. jQuery is treating the result for successful credentials exactly as it is treating the various results for invalid credentials.

Comment: Then either do a `view source` and see if extra spaces or enters are being echoed or change the if to `if (result.trim() != 'match')` and see if that solves it

Comment: make sure jQuery is seeing your result as text or html, it may think it has a JSON object or something so since it is in an object it does not == match

Answer (score 0):

If your remaining code working fine then Just change `window.location` code with `window.location.href = "home.php";` Here href used for location redirection

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `header("Location: home.php");` in the php login function on success. Like:

```
    if(!empty($user_id)){
        $_SESSION['id']   = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
        header("Location: home.php");
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```